# Proper way to obtain facebook comments for seo purpouse

Tags: php, facebook

I found this code:

```
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=" . $purl;
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
$fb_response = json_decode($requests);
```

But I am not finding any official FACEBOOK docs. Is there a better way, or this is the standard facebook way?

Also how do you suggest to implement the database schema?

For example i saw the commment id is something like this: `400711659874_19158387`
Should I make an id field of `CHAR(21)` ?

Thanks

Edit1:

found some doc (a blog post) about crawling fb comments:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample you're using is functionally correct.

Initially, you'll have to run a script to fetch comments for all the unique URL's on your site which have the FB comments plugin. To refresh that listing periodically, you can later use the 'comment.create' and 'comment.remove' events to trigger an AJAX request which updates the comments for that particular URL in the background.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest implementation to grab information from an external resources,
a more industry standard is using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php),

Here is the comparison from one of the old question :-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

**FB has the login mechanism to prevent unauthorized content grabbing**
There are some [SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) you can make use.

> Also how do you suggest to implement the database schema?
>
> For example i saw the commment id is something like this: 400711659874_19158387
> Should I make an id field of CHAR(21) ?

If the comments is tied to your website contents,
you should have a minimum of two columns,
one to store your website contents ID,
one for FB comment ID

varchar(21) is fine, as long can fit the maximum length of the FB comment ID

Comment: I am not asking this. I meant if there is a better way using some facebook apis. Or the graph.facebook.com is the standard way

Comment: AFAIK there aren't any FB API's providing this functionality, since scraping data from FB isn't allowed. I think this was stated somewhere in a developer forum for FB apps, but i can't remind where...

Comment: the -1 is not justified, I first saw your question is NOT discuss about the schema design. And where the hell you asking about the API method? You just asking using file_get_contents is a standard way.

Comment: @ajreal: i would toggle that -1 but it's locked now sorry

Comment: and @ajreal I know varchar(21) is fine as long as it can fit the maxium length (it's oblivious) but is that the right way ? ...

Comment: obviously you can not use a varchar(10), it get truncated. So, obvious question come with obvious answer ... moody-ing

Comment: @ajreal: no. Another possibility is to use 2 int(x) field. one for the right number one for the left number...

Comment: without knowing the actual purpose of the underscore, is pointless to split. **AND** how do you propose a optimize way to query after you split the comment ID?